# How to give multiple options for opening pdf,doc.pptx file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want solution for this----If I click on PDF,Doc,PPTX,Docx file then how to give multiple options for opening that file in flutter.
How to open that file in mobiles in build app like WPS office or something else.

```
This is my code to show files in listview:

    ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: attachments.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                    print (index);
                    return ListView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: CircleAvatar(
                                child: _getIcon(
                                    attachments[index].split('/').removeLast()),
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              subtitle:
                              Text(attachments[index].split('/').removeLast()),
                              onTap: (){}
                            ),
                          ),
                        ]);
                  })
```

This is output of code:[image]

Now on tap of file how to open that file in mobiles WPS office app.

Comment: show some code and explain your issue better

Comment: I have added my code

Answer (score 0):

TRy using https://pub.dev/packages/open_file. It can call native APP to open files with string result in flutter,support iOS(UTI) and android(intent)

Comment: actually the file stored on another machine I want to open that file in my mobile .I have path of that file  i.e     String fileUrl = 
widget.schoolDcUrl + "/container" + attachments[index];

Comment: I have pass this path means fileUrl to Open.file() function but its opening file

Comment: if you have the path as part of http you can just open it in default browser. Let browser decide what to do